# Overloading and overriding static and non static methods in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how overloading and overriding static and non static methods work. In fact, I am trying to understand how these methods can and cannot appear in parent and child classes in general. I came up with the below are the rules:

1. We cannot override static methods, but hide them. By hiding, we mean which method is executed is decided at compile time based on reference variable type, unlike overriding (, in which method is chosen for execution at run time based on instance type).
   e.g. Let `class B extends A`, then `static B.method()` hides `static A.method()`.
2. We can override instance methods.
   e.g. `B.method()` overrides `A.method()`.
3. Two or more methods with same signature cannot exist in the same class in any combination of static or non static.
   e.g. `B` cannot contains both `static method(float)` and `method(float)`.
4. Two or more methods with different signature can exist in the same class in any combination of static or non static.
   e.g. `B` can contain `static method()`, `static method(int)` and `method(float)`
5. A static method cannot override non static method.
   e.g. `B.method()` cannot override `static B.method()`
6. A non static method cannot override static method.
   e.g. `static B.method()` cannot override `B.method()`

Am I correct with these observations? Also did I miss any rule?

Answer (score 0):

The rules :

- `Polymorphism` applies to overriding, not to overloading.
- `Overriding` is a run-time concept while overloading is a compile-time concept.

Polymorphism ->
The real object type @runtime (and not the reference variable's type) determines which `overridde` method is used. In contrast, reference type determines which `overload` method is used at compile time.

Regarding static methods : 
They can not be **overridden**  but they can be **overloaded** and **hidden** in Java

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct with these observations?

They are mostly correct. I would change 3 and 4 to:

3. Two or more methods with same signature *after type erasure* cannot exist in the same class in any combination of static or non static.
4. Two or more methods with different signature *after type erasure* can exist in the same class in any combination of static or non static.

For example, you can't have `method(List<String>)` and `method(List<Integer>)` in the same class. In fact, you also can't have one of them in a parent class, and the other in a child class. Because either way, you are [*overloading a method where the formal parameter types of each overload erase to the same raw type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotOverload).

Also, you haven't mentioned any rules about overloading... The general rule is that as long as two methods are in the same class, (or one of them inherited from a parent class), and their names are the same, but they don't override each other --> They are overloads of each other.

Your "rules" are, in my opinion, useful enough for someone learning about Java, but if you interested in how to express this in a more rigorous way, check out the [Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html), specifically [§8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) on overriding & hiding. Most of your rules are either explicitly stated in there, or are a consequence of statement(s) in there. By reading the language spec, you can also find out what you have missed.